# Identity Providers with Xamarin Forms and Azure

Tags: facebook, azure, xamarin.forms

I'm a bit confused about Identity Providers in a project I'm doing with Xamarin Forms.

I configured Facebook as an IP with Azure Mobile Apps following this page 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-how-to-configure-facebook-authentication

It works, but my doubt is, how can I use the MobileServiceUser result of the authentication process to, for example, post to Facebook or get personal information from Facebook. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem. 
What I was trying to do is get information from Facebook after I have authenticated myself.

All I had to do was invoke

```
await client.InvokeApiAsync("/.auth/me");
```

After authentication and thats all, the response of that request has the token to access the Facebook API. These tokens are saved in Azure.

For more information:
https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think about it.

1. Identity providers are used to provide a third party guarantee of WHO a user is.
2. The Mobile SDK lets you do Authorization. So you can decide WHAT the user can do on YOUR service after you know WHO they are.

Any thing you are doing via facebook would still need to be done through the Facebook API/SDK using the token their Authentication process returned to you.